# Rails polymorphic relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use polymorphic relationship with rails 5.

I have difficulties to figure out how to finish my relations.

I have users, who can take reservations for hotels, restaurants, etc.

My purpose is to get hotels name and reservations when calling /users/{id} through API.

Here is my User model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :reservations, as: :reservable
     has_many :hotels, through: :reservations
end
```

My Hotel model :

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :reservations, as: :reservable
      belongs_to :users, through: :reservations
end
```

My Reservation model :

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :reservable, polymorphic: true
      belongs_to :users
      belongs_to :hotels
end
```

Migrations :

User :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Reservations :

```
class CreateReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :reservations do |t|
      t.belongs_to :hotel, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.datetime :date_from
      t.datetime :date_to

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class ReservationPolymorphism < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
      rename_column :reservations, :hotel_id, :reservable_id
      change_column :reservations, :reservable_id, polymorphic: true
      add_column :reservations, :reservable_type, :string
  end
end
```

Hotel :

```
class CreateHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :hotels do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.string :postal_code
      t.string :town

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I just have 1 line in my reservations table :

```
mysql> select * from reservations;
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | reservable_id | reservable_type | user_id | date_from           | date_to             | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |             1 | Hotel           |       1 | 2017-01-12 00:00:00 | 2017-01-15 00:00:00 | 2016-10-19 09:18:01 | 2016-10-19 09:18:01 |
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I have no result when using the API.

Here is what I get, using Rails console :

```
2.2.3 :001 > thomas = User.find(1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, first_name: "Thomas", last_name: "Dupont", email: "thomas.dupont@yopmail.com", created_at: "2016-10-18 21:12:12", updated_at: "2016-10-18 21:12:12"> 
2.2.3 :003 >   thomas.reservations
  Reservation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservations`.`reservable_id` = 1 AND `reservations`.`reservable_type` = 'User'
2.2.3 :005 > thomas.hotels
NameError: uninitialized constant User::Hotels
```

So I can see I make basic mistake with rails relations and polymorphism but I really can't find out where I'm wrong.

I think I made a mistake.
I assumed Polymorphism could be use to load other models and their tables (like "morphTo" with eloquent / laravel), whereas it's just to load a model which has no data representation (as described in this post : https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-polymorphism-to-make-a-better-activity-feed-in-rails )

Comment: Can you please remove the extra associations written in User and Hotel models. please remove the following, 'has_many :hotels, through: :reservations' from User and 'belongs_to :users, through: :reservations' from Hotel. and then run the queries in console

Comment: Just did it and still got the " Reservation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservations`.`reservable_id` = 1 AND `reservations`.`reservable_type` = 'User'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
" problem.

Comment: can you please remoe this too from reservations model, belongs_to :users
      belongs_to :hotels

Comment: Still get the same result. I think the pb is I'm using the relationship in "wrong way", since it's looking for 'User' type in reservations table whereas I want it to load Hotels reservations.

Comment: Can you please add the migration files too? of the above models?

Comment: please refactor your code as below. I checked the same code in my local system. And found that the extra associations brings the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess on viewing your code, you have written extra associations on top of the polymorphic association,

To create a polymorphic association, just the following code is enough. No need to pass extra association inside the model. Please refactor your code as follows,
User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :reservations, as: :reservable
end
```

Hotel model :

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :reservations, as: :reservable
end
```

Reservation model :

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :reservable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And in the migration file for reservations, add the reservable as below

```
t.references :reservable, polymorphic: true
```

Comment: Ok I got the first mistake I make : User is not reservable. User has_many reservations through user_id relations, not "reservable_id".

I have to figure out the user -> hotels relation to make it fully work.

Comment: It keeps seeking "2.2.3 :001 > u = User.find(1)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, first_name: "Thomas", last_name: "Dupont", email: "thomas.dupont@yopmail.com", created_at: "2016-10-18 21:12:12", updated_at: "2016-10-18 21:12:12"> 
2.2.3 :002 > u.reservations
  Reservation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservations`.`reservable_id` = 1 AND `reservations`.`reservable_type` = 'User'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> ". This is not the behavior I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i sorted this out :

This is the reservation model :

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :reservable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This is the hotel model :

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And the user model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :reservations
end
```

And how I got a results in rails console :

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 87452
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.2.3 :001 > u = User.find(1)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, first_name: "Thomas", last_name: "Dupont", email: "thomas.dupont@yopmail.com", created_at: "2016-10-18 21:12:12", updated_at: "2016-10-18 21:12:12"> 
2.2.3 :002 > u.reservations
  Reservation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservations`.`user_id` = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Reservation id: 1, reservable_id: 1, reservable_type: "Hotel", user_id: 1, date_from: "2017-01-12 00:00:00", date_to: "2017-01-15 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-10-19 09:18:01", updated_at: "2016-10-19 09:18:01">]> 
2.2.3 :003 > u.reservations.first.reservable
  Hotel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `hotels`.* FROM `hotels` WHERE `hotels`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Hotel id: 1, name: "HYATT REGENCY HOTEL", address: "3 Place du Général Kœnig", postal_code: "75017", town: "PARIS", created_at: "2016-10-19 08:36:55", updated_at: "2016-10-19 08:36:55">
```